# Differentiate 01 and 10 in digital logic

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I'm looking for a device with the following truth table:

[image]

The 00 and 11 case can be done with NOR and AND, but XOR cannot tell 01 and 10 apart.

Is there a device with such a truth table? If not, how can I make one?

I can think of one method, which adds a NOT in one of the inputs that turns 01 and 10 into 00 and 11, but it seems quite messy.

Comment: *"but it seems quite messy."* It may seem messy but it ***is*** the way things are done. Side note: In ASIC libraries you have special gates for that as well as other combinations like AOI (And Or Invert) gates with 2, or 3 inputs on AND and OR.

Comment: Real functions often require inverters.  Look up Karnaugh maps and you'll start to understand the classic route to manually resolving these, of course most of the time now they are digested by a logic compiler targeting hardware that actually works differently, for example an FPGA LUT, or perhaps still somewhere a classic PLD sum-of-products or product-of-sums architecture.  It's a relatively safe bet you aren't making an ASIC.

Comment: It is quite usual to employ not gates to have available both the inputs, and the negated inputs. How would you solve the problem if you had available IN1, IN2, IN1_negated and IN2_negated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are describing has a name -- it's called a *2-to-4 line decoder*, and the image below shows how it's typically implemented. There isn't any way of implementing this function in fewer standard gates.

[image]

(Image borrowed from [Wikipedia -- Decoder Example.svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Decoder_Example.svg))

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: But there are [not-quite standard gates](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G97) that can be configured for "AND with one inverted input".

Comment: @CL. And there are [other not-quite-standard gates](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G139) that could be used to implement the whole thing as one "gate". Which is why I qualified that statement. :)